# how to make app stop when screen turns off

Tags: android

I have created an exercise app with text-to-speech functionality that says exercise name and sound when it's time to rest. but when I turn the screen off app keeps working making the sound and saying the exercise name. I think it has something to do with activity lifecycle, but I am a beginner in android development, so I don't quite know them.

How can I make the app stop working when the screen is off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pause your TTS manager when your activity/fragment goes to the onPause()/onStop() state and becomes not visible to the end user.

Please, read about activities/fragments [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) and determine which state would be the best solution for your case. You can either override these lifecycle methods directly (the easiest way) or you can use the [Jetpack Lifecycle lib](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle) to create lifecycle-aware components (a cleaner approach if your TTS manager implementations exists as a separate class (and it should be so)).

Comment: Thanks! i was able to stop them with overriding the onStop method